# How to more completely validate CSV file when uploading to Shiny App?

Tags: r, validation, shiny, upload

**At the very bottom is now posted the complete resolved code, reflecting the solution offered by M. Jagan. This code offers the full cycle of both data uploads (with robust data validation) and downloads of user inputs. You can see how the `try()` function "tests" the upload to avoid unnecessarily crashing the App.**

When running the below code, the user can upload and download input data. The user can download and save inputs, and later retrieve those inputs via upload. I'm trying to improve the upload validation because in reality it will be very easy for the user to select an incorrect file and I'd rather flag with a warning rather than have the App crash like it does now.

All downloads are saved as a 2-column matrix with headers of X and Y. That (and the fact that it's a CSV) are my key upload validations per the below code. The App correctly downloads and uploads CSV data as shown in image 1 (download) and image 2 (upload) below, but crashes when it tries uploading incorrectly formatted CSV data per image 3 below.

So my questions are:

1. How do I specify which columns in the csv file to look for the "X" and "Y" headers? Currently it reads everywhere for X and Y headers. I tried `read.csv(...colClasses=c(NA, NA)))` as shown below, I also tried `read.csv(...)[ , 1:2]` and neither one works.
2. More generally, is there a way to abort the upload if it would otherwise cause an error or crash? Sort of like `if(iserror(...))` in Excel
3. OK now I'm pushing it, please feel free to ignore this if this is too much. Any way to move the upload warning into `modalDialog`? I can always move this to another post if I can't figure it out, after resolving the above.

MWE code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

interpol <- function(a, b) { # a = periods, b = matrix inputs
  c <- rep(NA, a)
  c[1] <- b[1]
  c[a] <- b[2]
  c <- approx(seq_along(c)[!is.na(c)], c[!is.na(c)], seq_along(c))$y 
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Optionally choose input file (csv)", accept = ".csv"),
      sliderInput('periods', 'Periods to interpolate over:', min=1, max=10, value=10),
      matrixInput("matrix1", 
                  value = matrix(c(1,5), 
                          ncol = 2, 
                          dimnames = list("Interpolate",c("X","Y"))
                  ),
                  cols =  list(names = TRUE),
                  class = "numeric"
      ),
      downloadButton("download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  input_file <- reactive({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    req(file)
    
    if(is.null(file))
      return(NULL)
    
    file_contents <- read.csv(file$datapath,header=TRUE,colClasses=c(NA, NA))
    required_columns <- c('X','Y')
    column_names <- colnames(file_contents)
    
    shiny::validate(
      need(ext == "csv", "Incorrect file type"),
      need(required_columns %in% column_names, "Incorrect file type")
    )
    
    file_contents
    
  })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    input_file()
  })
  
  data <- function(){
    tibble(
      X = seq_len(input$periods),
      Y = interpol(input$periods,matrix(c(input$matrix1[1,1],input$matrix1[1,2])))
    )
  }  
  
  output$plot<-renderPlot({plot(data(),type="l",xlab="Periods (X)", ylab="Interpolated Y values")})
  
  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    updateMatrixInput(session, 
                      inputId = "matrix1", 
                      value = matrix(as.matrix(input_file()),
                                     ncol=2,
                                     dimnames = list("Interpolate",c("X","Y"))
                              )
    )
                      
  })
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Inputs","csv",sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(input$matrix1, file,row.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now the resolved code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(shinyMatrix)

nms <- c("X", "Y") # < Matrix variable names (headers)

interpol <- function(a, b) { # < a = periods, b = matrix inputs
  c <- rep(NA, a)
  c[1] <- b[1]
  c[a] <- b[2]
  c <- approx(seq_along(c)[!is.na(c)], c[!is.na(c)], seq_along(c))$y 
  return(c)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Optionally choose input file (csv)", accept = ".csv"),
      sliderInput('periods', 'Periods to interpolate over:', min=1, max=10, value=10),
      matrixInput("matrix1", 
                  "Values to interpolate:",
                  value = matrix(c(1,5),ncol = 2,dimnames = list(NULL,nms)),
                  cols =  list(names = TRUE),
                  rows = list(names = FALSE),
                  class = "numeric"
      ),
      downloadButton("download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      plotOutput("plot"),
      verbatimTextOutput("verb")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  uploadData <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    validate(need(identical(tools::file_ext(input$file$datapath),"csv"),"Invalid extension"))
    try(read.csv(input$file$datapath, header = TRUE))
  })
  
  observeEvent(uploadData(), {
    if(is.data.frame(uploadData()) && 
       all(nms %in% names(uploadData())) && 
       all(vapply(uploadData()[nms],is.numeric,NA))){
          updateMatrixInput(session,"matrix1",as.matrix(uploadData()[nms]))
          hideFeedback("file")
        } 
    else {
      showFeedbackWarning("file", "Invalid upload.")
    }
  })

  data <- function(){
    tibble(
      X = seq_len(input$periods),
      Y = interpol(input$periods,matrix(c(input$matrix1[1,1],input$matrix1[1,2])))
    )
  }  
  
  output$plot<-renderPlot({plot(data(),type="l",xlab="Periods (X)", ylab="Interpolated Y values")})
  output$verb <- renderPrint(class(uploadData()))  
  
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("Inputs","csv",sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(input$matrix1, file,row.names=FALSE)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: For (2), you can do `file_contents <- try(read.csv(...))` and validate that `is.data.frame(file_contents)` is `TRUE`. See `?try`.

Comment: For (1), have you tried `file_contents[c("X", "Y")]`?

Comment: OK let me research try(). Basically if the uploading and related connected objects (matrix update, plot) causes something funny to happen, I'd like the upload ignored and just truck on; user can try uploading again or manually inputting into the matrix. Your last comment for (1), where would that go? I've tried it in several places and I get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a minimal version of your app (without interpolation or downloads) that I think addresses (1) and (2) and your desire for an existing matrix and plot to be preserved in the event that an invalid upload occurs. You should be able to rebuild your app by modifying this skeleton, but, before doing that, you should try to understand how this app works.

Note that I've added a dependency on package `shinyFeedback`, which places warning messages near the appropriate input panels. Let me know if that's a problem...

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinyFeedback")
library("shinyMatrix")

## Your variable names
nms <- c("X", "Y")

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", label = "CSV file", accept = ".csv"),
      matrixInput("mat", label = "Matrix", value = matrix(rnorm(12L), 6L, 2L, dimnames = list(NULL, nms)), class = "numeric", rows = list(names = FALSE))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      verbatimTextOutput("verb")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rawdata <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    try(read.csv(input$file$datapath, header = TRUE))
  })

  observeEvent(rawdata(), {
    ## If 'rawdata()' is a data frame with numeric variables named 'nms'
    if (is.data.frame(rawdata()) && all(nms %in% names(rawdata())) && all(vapply(rawdata()[nms], is.numeric, NA))) {
      ## Then update matrix by extracting those variables, ignoring the rest (if any)
      updateMatrixInput(session, "mat", as.matrix(rawdata()[nms]))
      ## And suppress warning if visible
      hideFeedback("file")
    } else {
      ## Otherwise show warning
      showFeedbackWarning("file", "Invalid upload.")
    }
  })
  
  ## Plots matrix rows as points
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(input$mat))
  ## Prints "try-error" if 'read.csv' threw error, "data.frame" otherwise
  output$verb <- renderPrint(class(rawdata()))  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is code that you can use to create test files. Each one tests a different behaviour of the app.

```r
## OK
cat("X,Y,Z\na,1,3,5\nb,2,4,6\n", file = "test1.csv")
## OK: file contents matter, not file extension
cat("X,Y,Z\na,1,3,5\nb,2,4,6\n", file = "test2.txt")
## Missing 'X'
cat("W,Y,Z\na,1,3,5\nb,2,4,6\n", file = "test3.csv")
## 'X' is not numeric
cat("X,Y,Z\na,hello,3,5\nb,world,4,6\n", file = "test4.csv")
## Not a valid CSV file
cat("read.csv\nwill,not,like,this,file\n", file = "test5.csv")
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should address your need

```
shiny::validate(
  need(ext == "csv", "Incorrect file type"),
  need(required_columns %in% column_names, "Incorrect file type"),
  need(sum(!column_names %in% required_columns)==0, "Incorrect columns in file")
)
```

**UPDATE:** if you are ok to modify your checks, you can do the following.

```
shiny::validate(
  need(ext == "csv", "Incorrect file type"),
  need(sum(required_columns %in% column_names)==2 & sum(!column_names %in% required_columns)==0, "Incorrect file type")
)
```

Comment: Thanks YBS, that works in the case of the example I posted where X and Y were in the 2nd and 3rd columns of the csv, instead of the first 2 columns of the csv where they should be located. But how about a general error check, whereby if there to be an error (crashing the App), the upload (and related reactions of plotting and updating the matrix) are simply rejected? And in this case of error the App doesn't crash, nothing happens, and the user just inputs into the matrix or the user searches for the correct file to upload.

Comment: The above validate is not working? You can combine 2nd and 3rd check.  See updated answer.

Comment: The posted Update still causes a crash, when trying to upload a wrong csv like that one I show in newly posted image 4 above (I edited my original post to show image 4). I get the message "Warning: Error in read.table: more columns than column names [No stack trace available]" when simulating an erroneous user upload for image 4. Though this Update does work for image 3 error! I'm wondering if a more general approach, like using try() to simply ignore an upload that would cause a crash, is better. There are countless user error possibilities, can't catch them all in validate(need(...))

Comment: For me, it works fine as it shows "Incorrect file type" when you select a file with only X variable. The statement `sum(required_columns %in% column_names)==2` is checking if you have X and Y variables, and the statement `sum(!column_names %in% required_columns)==0` is checking if you have any other variable(s) in your file.  If either statement fails, it displays "Incorrect file type".